# TZipFile, архивировать с паролем можно, но как разархивировать с паролем

Tags: delphi

Скачав модуль «*EncryptedZipFile*» от [сюда](https://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/05/07/tzipfile-with-password-encryption-part-3/) , можно архивировать с паролем
Например с паролем «*1*»:

```
var
  ef: TEncryptedZipFile;
begin
  try
    ef := TEncryptedZipFile.Create('1');
    try
      ef.Open('d:\test.zip', zmWrite);
      ef.Add('d:\test.bin', 'd:\test.bin', zcDeflate);
    finally
      ef.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Я пробовал разархивировать:

```
 var
  ef: TEncryptedZipFile;
begin
  try
    ef := TEncryptedZipFile.Create('1');
    try
      ef.Open('d:\test.zip', zmRead);
      ef.Extract('test.bin', 'd:\test.bin', true);
      ef.Close;
    finally
      ef.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

но у меня на строке:

```
ef.Extract('test.bin', 'd:\', true);
```

выдает ошибку:

> ```
> Project PrArch.exe raised exception class EZipException with message
> 'The specified file was not found'.
> ```

возможно я **не попадаю** в архив.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема не в <s>бобине</s> пароле, но в неправильном указании аргументов для методов.
**Во-первых**, в данном коде

> ef.Add('d:\test.bin', **'d:\test.bin'**, zcDeflate);

Вы указали некорректный аргумент (выделен жирным), о котором справка говорит, что:

> ArchiveFileName is the full path of the file in the archive

Это так: необходимо указать имя файла (необязательно совпадающее с именем файла на диске).

**Во-вторых**, при открытии архива Вы пишите:

> ef.Extract('test.bin', **'d:\test.bin'**, true);

Но это неверное указание аргумента (выделен жирным), поскольку справка говорит, что:

> Path represents the location, on the disk, where the file will be extracted

т.е., следует указать не *полный путь к файлу* (с его именем и расширением), но именно путь к папке\корню диска, по которому файл должен быть помещен после распаковки архива.

Ошибка, которую Вы получаете при распаковке, связана с тем, что в Вашем первоначальном коде Вы распаковываете архив по адресу `D:\` + `имя_файла_в_архиве`, поэтому директория с именем `D:\test.bin\test.bin` не существует. Таким образом, необходимо немного видоизменить аргументы, указанные в методах `Add` и `Extract`.

Советую Вам переписать Ваш код, а также (не сочтите за грубость) почаще заглядывать в справку ;)

Модифицированный код ниже.
*Создание архива:*

```
ef := TEncryptedZipFile.Create('1');
try
  ef.Open('d:\test.zip', zmWrite);
  ef.Add('d:\test.bin', 'test.bin', zcDeflate);
finally
  ef.Free;
end;
```

*Открытие архива (распаковка):*

```
ef := TEncryptedZipFile.Create('1');
try
  ef.Open('d:\test.zip', zmRead);
  ef.Extract('test.bin', 'd:\', true);
  ef.Close;
finally
  ef.Free;
end;
```

Полезная информация:

1. [About TZipFile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.Zip.TZipFile)
2. [Add to Zip method](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.Zip.TZipFile.Add)
3. [Extract from Zip method](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.Zip.TZipFile.Extract)

Comment: **Большое спасибо** Dima, понял, я не с правильными параметрами аривировал, и потом мучался с разархивированием...

Comment: @Konstantin78, Ничего страшного, главное быть внимательным с аргументами) P.S. Я уж подумал, что это модератор удалил Ваш комментарий